# Facebook app with Kohana 3

Tags: facebook, integration, kohana-3

Using FB in a site is simple

```
require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
// Create our Application instance.

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'zzzz',
  'secret' => 'zzz',
  'cookie' => true,
));
```

I have tried the following in the bootstrap.php

```
include Kohana::find_file('vendors/Facebook', 'facebook');
//gives correct path, facebook.php is 755
```

The Facebook class is written as:

```
class Controller_Facebook extends Controller{}

$this->facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => 'zzz', 'secret' => 'zzz',  'cookie' => true,));

//the line above causes the error below
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Facebook' not found
```

Has anyone solved this problem before?
If so, then how do I access $this->facebook in the controllers

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a typo in the path, you want:

```
include Kohana::find_file('vendor/Facebook', 'facebook');
```

'vendor/' instead of 'vendors/' in the path.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on a zombor's [Facebook module](https://github.com/zombor/Kohana-Facebook). You can extend it for your needs (seems like it has only authorization features).

Comment: I looked at that one, it seems insufficient.